# How do I remove rows based on time, location and individual criteria in R

Tags: r, timespan

I'm trying to remove redundant data rows from a gigantic dataset. For the same individual, at the same location, on the same day, I want to keep just one detection for every 10 minutes time range. So for example if individual 1 stays around station 6 for 20 minutes, instead of 200 or so detections I just want to keep 2, one for every 10 minutes he's there. Here is an example dataset:

```
datetime<-c("2020-12-30 23:03:24","2020-12-30 23:04:25","2020-12-28 23:06:20", "2020-12-26 12:02:10","2020-12-26 12:07:26","2020-12-26 12:10:07", "2018-05-11 05:02:05","2018-05-11 05:03:07", "2018-05-11 05:13:25", "2018-05-11 05:14:27")
dt<-as.POSIXct(datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
i<-c('ind1','ind1','ind1', 'ind2', 'ind2', 'ind2', 'ind1', 'ind1', 'ind1', 'ind4')
l<-c('station1', 'station1', station1','station2','station2','station3','station1','station1','station2','station6')
stack<-data.frame(dt, i,l)
```

The expected resulting dataframe:

```
                    dt    i        l
1  2020-12-30 23:03:24 ind1 station1
2  2020-12-30 23:04:25 ind1 station1
3  2020-12-28 23:06:20 ind1 station1
4  2020-12-26 12:02:10 ind2 station2
5  2020-12-26 12:07:26 ind2 station2
6  2020-12-26 12:10:07 ind2 station3
7  2018-05-11 05:02:05 ind1 station1
8  2018-05-11 05:03:07 ind1 station1
9  2018-05-11 05:13:25 ind1 station2
10 2018-05-11 05:14:27 ind4 station6
```

Here is what I have tried to code so far:

```
#Separate date and time
stack <- tidyr::separate(stack, dt, c("date", "time"), sep = " ")

#Merge columns location (l), individual (i) and date (date)
    data_set_merged <- stack%>%
      unite("Merged_sample",  c("i", "l", "date"), remove=FALSE)

#Order dataset chronologically 
data_set_merged %>% arrange(ymd(data_set_merged$date))

#Count number of minutes between every group of detection
data_set_merged$time<-as.POSIXct(as.character(data_set_merged$time), format="%H:%M:%S")
value <-diff(data_set_merged$time)

#Add NA value at the end, since no difference between last value and nothing
Adding_NA_value <- append(value , "NA")

New_data_frame_with_column<- data_set_merged %>%
  dplyr::mutate (Time_intervall_seconds = Adding_NA_value)

#Group_by sample, site, year and day and select the observations with > 10 min (= less than 600 seconds) replicates
Final_data_frame <- New_data_frame_with_column %>%
  group_by(Merged_sample)%>%
  filter (Time_intervall_seconds>= 600)
```

This code deletes more than juste the redundant data: if two rows are less than 600 seconds, it deletes both instead of just one, so I'm losing information. I also don't know if it is only calculating the time difference for each group - I don't want to delete detections between individuals, or between locations for the same individual, I really only want it for the same location + individual + date.
I tried ordering it chronologically to get a time interval that makes sense, but then the interval is not calculated by group anymore.
I'm still quite new at R and I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be sososo welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will block the data into 10 minute intervals

```
library(slider)
block(stack, stack$dt, period = "minute", every = 10)
```

Odd as it sounds, it looks like the way to do this is block the intervals, then convert it back to a dataframe retaining the blocking in a column.  Then you can simply group by (i, l, bucket) and sample one from each.  you probably want to set the origin option in the block statement so you know where the cuts land, I just let them fall where they may.

```
f <- function(x) {t <- block(x, x$dt, period = "minute", every = 10) %>% tibble()}
fr <- f(stack) %>% mutate(bucket=row_number()) %>% 
                   unnest()

fr %>% group_by(i, l, bucket) %>% group_modify( ~ sample_n(.x, 1))

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   i, l, bucket [7]
  i     l        bucket dt                 
  <chr> <chr>     <int> <dttm>             
1 ind1  station1      1 2018-05-11 05:03:07
2 ind1  station1      5 2020-12-28 23:06:20
3 ind1  station1      6 2020-12-30 23:04:25
4 ind1  station2      2 2018-05-11 05:13:25
5 ind2  station2      3 2020-12-26 12:07:26
6 ind2  station3      4 2020-12-26 12:10:07
7 ind4  station6      2 2018-05-11 05:14:27
```